# Move SVN repository without svnadmin dump/load

Tags: svn, migration, svnadmin

I have a huge server Subversion repository which I should move to an external mounted partition. Of course there are possibility to make `svnadmin` `load` / `dump` or `svnadmin hotcopy`, but in my situation it could take a lot of time, because of the size of the repository.

Could I avoid this stage and just to move the whole folder to new partition without to break any internal relations to the system location ?

I would like to do something like :

```
mv /path/repository /other_path/repository
```

I like this possibility with local client's repository, and it will help a lot, if such operation could be done with server repository also.

Comment: Yes, exactly. For me it's the same. Changing the absolute location on the filesystem of the server.

Comment: I just wanted to mention that the path changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can move it **if** you make sure that nobody accesses the repository while you're moving it.

**Keep in mind**: this might render existing working copies invalid, users might need to do a `svn switch --relocate` so that their working copies point to the new location.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, of course, I will stop the vhost of the current repository during copy. Normally, it will be on the same server, so it's the same URL for the user, all the configuration will be changed in Apache's configuration, so normally don't need to relocate.

Comment: Works fine, tested. No relocate need in our case. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

In theory yes, everything related to your SVN repository is contained within the hidden `.svn` folders.